# node.js: Redirecting stdin,stdout of a (different) console application

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write an admin tool for Unturned (it's a zombie survival game). The server to that game runs in a terminal. I wanted to somehow get the live output of that console and at the same time being able to write to the terminal so I can control the server with my admin tool written in node.js. I tried to google/search for a solution but am not entirely sure what to look for. So far I tried different things with child_process but to no avail. Is such a thing even possible and when yes how?

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const proc = spawn("Unturned.exe", ["-batchmode", "-nographics", "+secureserver/servername", "", "", "", ]);

proc.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

proc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

proc.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

and another.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const proc = spawn("Unturned.exe", ["-batchmode", "-nographics", "+secureserver/servername", "", "", "", ], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] });

proc.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log("stdout: "+data);
});

proc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log("stderr: "+data);
});

proc.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Both don't work (first one doesn't get input/output, second one doesn't even successfully start the server).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Unturned.exe` is sending output to `stdout` and `stderr`. Can you do this: `Unturned.exe -batchmode -nographics +secureserver/servername >data.txt` ?

Comment: The output is what the first code gave me back. So I guess it doesn't send to stdout but somewhere else. Is there a way to figure out what steam it outputs/inputs to and then read/write that?

Comment: In windows an exe could send data directly to the console bypassing the std streams (not the same console that nodejs uses). If that the case you could not capture it